# Alignment of two slightly different vector layers

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, vector, alignment, affine-transformation

I have to vector layers. It seems like two of them are describing the same features, but slightly offset from each other.

[image: Original data]

[image: Trying to align the central part]

I have tried to align them manually using the Advanced Digitising Tools (Move feature) in QGIS with no success. It seems that these two layers have two slightly different geometric properties, perhaps affine transformation or projection. In metadata, however, the projection of these two layers is the same (EPSG:3857).

The question is: is there a way to align these layers correctly (like finding the affine transformation, if that is the problem)?

[Here](https://github.com/asmolina/forest-disease/blob/dc86cde35fc2932c1585f539e4de15b5cf199c55/3662.geojson) and [here](https://github.com/asmolina/forest-disease/blob/dc86cde35fc2932c1585f539e4de15b5cf199c55/3137.geojson) the links to these layers (github repo).